# Why only half of this texture fits my model?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

I downloaded the model of a hand and it came with a texture.

I did a few steps that involved UV unwrapping in order to texture it. I can't remember the steps exactly.

When I select the bottom face of the arm, this is what I get:
[image]

To me it looks pretty good because the tiles fit almost perfectly into the arm texture. Now when I select the top face of the arm it's a different story:

[image]

In order to make it fit I would need to bend the fingers. I already tried it, but it sucks.

What did I do wrong? How can I make the top part match the texture well?

Comment: Do remember how you unwrapped it? It looks like you might have changed the UVs when you unwrapped it, which is why it doesn't match the texture. Check to see if the original model without your changes has uvs that fit the texture.

Comment: You need to create a seam that runs across the middle of the arm, and unwrap top and bottom separately.

Comment: I opened the model on a new Blender file and it seems the texture came totally ready. I probably assumed it was not textured because I was using Solid view LOL. The problem is that I did too many changes to this model that depend on an armature. Can't just reimport it. Is there a way to reset the UV mapping to what was in the beginning? You may be asking how I managed to screw it up. I tried to follow a tutorial...

Comment: I will try @susu's suggestion.